# LLVM unable to get a required analysis

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a pass that needs information about loops. Therefore I am overriding `getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage&)` to let the pass manager know that my pass depends on `LoopInfoWrapperPass`. However, when I try to get the result of that analysis, LLVM asserts that the analysis wasn't required by my pass. Here's a simple pass that I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <llvm/Pass.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h>

struct Example : public ModulePass {
    static char ID;
    Example() : ModulePass(ID) {}

    bool runOnModule(Module& M) override {
        errs() << "what\n";
        LoopInfo& loops = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
        loops.print(errs());

        return false;
    }

    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage& AU) const override {
        errs() << "here\n";
        AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>();
    }
};

char Example::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Example> X("example", "an example", false, false);
```

When I run this pass, the two debug statements are printed in the correct order (here then what) but when `getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>()` is called, I get this assertion error:

```
opt: /home/matt/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:211: AnalysisType& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID(llvm::AnalysisID) const [with AnalysisType = llvm::LoopInfoWrapperPass; llvm::AnalysisID = const void*]: Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed.
```

This is the same method that is given in LLVM's [documentation on writing passes](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#specifying-interactions-between-passes), so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LoopInfoWrapperPass`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfoWrapperPass.html) is derived from `FunctionPass`. Your `Example` class, however, derives from `ModulePass`. It works on the module level, so you'll need to tell `LoopInfoWrapperPass` which function you want to analyze. Basically, you might want to loop every function `f` in the module, and use `getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>(f)`.

Alternatively, the easiest way to fix the code above is to replace `ModulePass` with `FunctionPass` and `runOnModule(Module& M)` with `runOnFunction(Function& F)`. Then, `getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>()` should work just fine.